# MYSQL sync data overwriting

Tags: mysql

I'm in trouble. I make a system where a Master DB and three child DB in remote Location.

Child DB's are on offline mode. When internet come, it sends data to Master DB.

But Issue is:
IN Master DB , Student Table Last inserted ID is 12 (primary key with auto increment)

Child A have Same data and Child B have also Same data.

Now Child a insert new Data into student table and sync with Master DB.
So, Master DB ID=13 and One Student is "John".

Now Child B also insert one data and its local table ID is 13 and Student is "Maria".

When Child B Sync with Master, I lost "JOHN" , its overwrites with "Maria".

How Can I solve this issue?

Comment: You probably need a Queue to be implemented which takes care of this. Basically, Child should send to Queue and Queue will send to Master (First In First Out)

Comment: Can you please briefly explain. What kind queue? I'm trying with navicat and SqlLog . Any other tools need?